# How to debug this shell script not working on cron?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I have a shell script below. This already works by doing sh start_script.sh

But I want this to work automatically using cron jobs. Already made it executable using **chmod +x**

Below is shell script and the cron job:

```
2 * * * * /home/glenn/projects/database_dump/backup/script_backupMongoDB.sh
```

```
#!/bin/sh
TIMESTAMP=`date +%F-%H%M%S`
FILENAME=configurator_`date +%m%d%y%H`_$TIMESTAMP.tar.gz
DEST=/home/glenn/projects/database_dump/backup
SERVER=127.0.0.1:27017
DBNAME=siaphaji-cms


DUMPFOLDER=$DEST/$DBNAME
DAYSTORETAINBACKUP="7"

# DUMP TO DEST FOLDER
mongodump -h $SERVER -d $DBNAME --out $DEST;

# COMPRESS THE DUMPFOLDER AND NAME IT FILENAME
tar -zcvf $FILENAME $DUMPFOLDER

# DELETE DUMP FOLDER
rm -rf $DUMPFOLDER

find $DEST -type f -name '*.tar.gz' -mtime +$DAYSTORETAINBACKUP -exec rm {} +
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processes launched via cron only have a default environment. You should use a full path for all non standard commands, and add all the required environment variables (at least for `mongodump`) in the script itself.

Comment: I did this one  ```MONGODUMP_PATH="/usr/bin/mongodump"``` and change mongodump to $MONGODUMP but its still not working. How can I debug this to show what is the error? Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Check the environment differences, especially the value of the PATH variable in each case (when it works, and when not).